# How to explain this strange comint behavior?

Tags: comint, point, motion

I have the following issue with `comint`, it could be a bug.  It holds
true in different derived modes, such as python or gdb.  How to see
the strange behavior:

1. `run-python`
2. Enter some stuff: <kbd>M-20 a</kbd>, don't press <kbd>RET</kbd>
3. Eval `(- (line-end-position) (line-beginning-position))`. It returns 20, which is correct.
4. Move point before `>>>`. <kbd>C-a</kbd> won't work, do <kbd>C-p C-a C-n</kbd> instead.
5. Eval `(- (line-end-position) (line-beginning-position))`. It returns 4, which is wrong.

Could someone explain this behavior? And if it's not a bug, what's the
work-around to get 20 instead of 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could someone explain this behavior?

The documentation of `line-end-position` has a note at the end that explains this behavior:

> This function constrains the returned position to the current field
>   unless that would be on a different line than the original,
>   unconstrained result.  If N is nil or 1, and a rear-sticky field ends
>   at point, the scan stops as soon as it starts.  **To ignore field
>   boundaries bind `inhibit-field-text-motion` to `t`**.

Same for `line-beginning-position`.

So, in your example

```
(let ((inhibit-field-text-motion t)) (- (line-end-position) (line-beginning-position)))
```

consistently evaluates to `24` at any position on that line (`4` characters of the prompt and `20` `a`s).